# Dynamic array of COM objects

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an ATL COM object which needs to expose a collection of other COM objects, so clients can find out how many objects are in the collection (via a simple `Count` property which I can provide) and access the objects using its index.  This collection of objects is dynamic - the count is not fixed - and I don't know how many there will be when my main (parent) object is constructed (so I can't create these objects in my `FinalConstruct` for example).  The objects I want to expose only have read-only properties.

What I want to do is somehow create a `std::vector` of these objects the first time they are required.  I want to use ATL smart COM pointers where possible so I don't need to manually manage reference counts, etc. but I'm not sure whether I should be using `CComPtr`, 'CComQIPtr', etc.

Assuming the objects I want to return are called `IChild`, I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
std::vector<CComPtr<IChild> > children;
...
CComPtr<IChild> child;
// Somehow instantiate an IChild?
...
children.push_back(child);

STDMETHODIMP Parent::GetAt(LONG index, IChild** pRet)
{
  *pRet = children[index];
}
```

If anyone has any pointers on how I can achieve this, I would be very welcome.  There is an [excellent article on exposing a static object](http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/12.htm), but I can't find anything on the particular problem in hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `std::vector< CComPtr<IChild> >` is the way to do it - you will get a dynamic array of `IChild*` that manages the lifetime of `IChild`-derived objects. Once you want to convert the `IChild*` to a derived interface you'll have to use `QueryInterface()` the same way as you would use `dynamic_cast` with C++ objects.

There's no point to use `CComQIPtr` for the array. The primary use of `CComQIPtr` is to have a convenient way to call `QueryInterface()` on a pointer to an object that maybe implements the interface of interest. Instead of calling `QueryInterface()` and checking the result you invoke the `CComQIPtr` constructor and check whether the resulting object contains a non-null pointer. You could use `CComQIPtr` in the code that uses your array, but there's no point in using it for the array itself.

Comment: Actually, as of MSVS2010, it has to be `std::vector<CAdapt<CComPtr<IChild>>>` because of the unfortunate operator& overload:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/25/stl-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx

Comment: Although, CAdapt isn't needed in C++11:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285016/do-vectors-of-ccomptr-still-need-cadapt

Comment: Is it also ok to use an `std::vector` of `ATL::CComObject`s?

Comment: @FelixDombek Storing reference-counted objects in `std::vector` is hardly ok.

Answer (score 2):

`CComPtr<...>` assumes that you assign it a compatible interface. `CComQIPtr<...>` calls `IUnknown::QueryInterface` to get the right interface. That's why it takes an additional `GUID` as a template parameter.

For your purposes, you should go with `CComPtr`, since you know you will always be initializing entries with an `IChild`.