# Do vectors of CComPtr still need CAdapt?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, atl

STL has `std::addressof` which gets the true address of an object even if it overloads `operator &`. `ATL::CAdapt` was required to workaround this problem when storing `CComPtrs` in `std::vectors`.

Anyway, I'm wondering, with C++11, should `std::vector` be able to cope with containing `CComPtr`'s directly without `CAdapt` being necessary?

More specifically, I'm using VS 2013. Would that support `vector` without `CAdapt`?

Comment: AFAIK no they don't need it with `vector` in VS2013, however for compatibility reasons you may wish to continue using `CAdapt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs6acf5x.aspx):

> This was most commonly necessary for C++ Standard Library containers
>   prior to support for the C++11 Standard, but C++11 Standard Library
>   containers automatically work with types that have overloaded
>   operator&().

This reads like you don't need `CAdapt` anymore because Visual Studio 2013 comes with a C++11 STL.